# can ELMAH detect ASP.NET exception logged only in event log?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, elmah.mvc, eventlog-source

I configured ELMHA on my ASP.NET MVC application but still not able to see in ELMHA logs some exceptions that I have only in the EvenLogs as Warning (example below)

> Event code: 3005
>   Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 3/8/2019 8:21:24 AM
>   Event time (UTC): 3/8/2019 8:21:24 AM
>   Event ID: 475a4611ce9647daa7913ba0054bf7c1
>   Event sequence: 10
>   Event occurrence: 1
>   Event detail code: 0
>   Application information:
>
> ```
> Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/OData-19-131964485503191222 
> Trust level: Full 
> Application Virtual Path: /OData 
> Application Path: .... 
> Machine name: DCSEUIRLSSSRS01    Process information: 
> Process ID: 15508 
> Process name: w3wp.exe 
> Account name: IIS APPPOOL\ODataReportService    Exception information: 
> Exception type: ArithmeticException
> Exception message: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.
>
> Request information: 
> Request URL: .... 
> Request path: /odata/api/Orders 
> User host address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
> User: ... 
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: BasicAuth 
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ODataReportService    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 192 
> Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\ODataReportService 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace: 
> Custom event details:
> ```

Comment: Think you need some more details here. At least I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: the issue is that I found some exceptions  logged in EventLogs that I don't see in ELMHA logs. exceptions seem are caught by the Asp.NET Health Monitoring only

Comment: And your application is named ODataReportService or something like that?

Comment: Yes that's the application name

Comment: Do you see any errors logged to ELMAH? What happens if you navigate to /elmah.axd? Can you share your web.config file?